# Escaping "." in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
    $imageurl = $pagename1; 
    $imageurl = preg_replace('/.asp/', .$g_sites_img2.'.jpg', $pagename1);
?>
```

I am trying to escape the `.` in the `preg_replace`.

I have also tried:

```
<?php
    $imageurl = $pagename1;
    $imageurl = preg_replace('/\.asp/', .$g_sites_img2.'\.jpg', $pagename1);
?>
```

Why is it still giving me an error?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What is your code doing that it shouldn't be doing?  What is your code not doing that it should?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: It gives me a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/game1/public_html/includes/standard_images_screenshot_2.php on line 1

Comment: The code takes the page name, and convert it to an image, and then use imagick to (get the image) and then insert the image into the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an extra `.` before `$g_sites_img2`.

```
$imageurl = preg_replace('/\.asp/', .$g_sites_img2.'\.jpg', $pagename1);?>
                                    ^ Here's your problem
```

I concur with @dtbarne -- `preg_replace()` is totally unnecessary here. You should be using `str_replace()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Rafe, I like the way you used to highlight the problem!

Comment: What is the difference between preg_replace and str_replace?

Comment: @Gerald preg_replace takes a regular expression and str_replace just takes a plain old string. In your case, you're just replacing a plain old string, so you don't need a regular expression.

Comment: I am new to PHP used to code in ASP for many years, and must say I am impressed with all the various functions that comes with PHP

Comment: @Gerald it's really a PITA because there's a trillion functions, with inconsistent names and arguments, and there all in the global namespace. There's a lot of stuff there, but it's very messy.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like preg_replace is necessary.

Why can't you just use str_replace? Anyway, you've got a syntax error (an extra period).

```
$imageurl = preg_replace('/\.asp/', $g_sties_img2 . '.jpg', $pagename1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php $imageurl = preg_replace('/\.asp/', $g_sites_img2.'\.jpg', $pagename1);?>
```

Notice the missing leading `.` in the 2nd argument of the `preg_replace()` call. Also, there is no need for the first line since you're writing the result of `preg_replace` to that variable anyway.